# What is the meaning of "Han was Han about it"?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

In "*Star Wars The Last Jedi (2017)*", after Rey's first lesson in Jedi training, in a dimly lit cave, Luke says to Rey:

> For many years, there was balance and then I saw Ben. My nephew with that mighty Skywalker blood. And in my hubris, I thought I could train him, I could pass on my strengths. **Han was Han about it**,  but... Leia trusted me with her son.

Comment: From context, I think he was referring to Han's skepticism about the Force in general, "Hokey religions and ancient weapons are no match for a good blaster at your side, kid."

Comment: It means Han shot first.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It means that the actions and motivations of Han Solo are distinctive enough that you can use his name as an eponym to get your point across.

Han Solo is (at least outwardly) a cynical, disagreeable, detached, and stubborn individual. So when Luke says, "Han was Han about it", he means that Han was being cynical and/or disagreeable and/or detached and/or stubborn about it, *per usual*.